# Start Activity For Result Not return to calling activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I have a fragment which calling Select Image from gallery Intent like this

```
  Intent intent=new Intent();
  intent.setType("image/*");
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Complete Action Using"),1);
```

I am successfully execute above method which start phone gallery and i can select image from there but app should return back to calling fragment but its not,even i can see **onActivityonResult calling in LogCat**

I also have one more get location from map which returned back to calling fragment but when picking image i am not coming back to calling activity instead it shows parent activity first fragment

Here is my **onActivityResult**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode==1 && resultCode==getActivity().RESULT_OK){

        Log.d(TAG,"Request Code is 1 Running: "+requestCode+" "+resultCode);
        Uri imageNameURL=data.getData();
        Log.d(TAG,imageNameURL.toString());
        ImagePath=getPath(imageNameURL);
        Log.d(TAG,"onActivityResult "+ImagePath);
        bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImagePath);

    }
    else if (requestCode==2 && resultCode==getActivity().RESULT_OK){

        Log.d(TAG,"Request Code 2 Running");
        LatLngBounds LL= PlacePicker.getLatLngBounds(data);
        double lat=LL.northeast.latitude;
        double longi=LL.northeast.longitude;
        double lat2=LL.southwest.latitude;
        double longi2=LL.southwest.longitude;            
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's possible that the calling activity is crashing when it tries to load that bitmap. You should post a logcat with any error messages and describe exactly what does happen, because I am not sure I understand from what you posted so far.

Comment: There is no error in log i can only see that on activity result is calling but my map activity is return back to same fragment and also i see image's on activityresult log in LogCat

Comment: Don't filter the logcat, maybe you will see relevant exceptions or crashes.

Comment: @DavidWasser I always set my logcat at **verbose**

Comment: I don't mean that. I mean do not filter by your application's package name. Most IDEs automatically set up a logcat filter using the application's package name. You will miss any exceptions or messages that are generated by the android framework if you use this type of filter, and often these are exactly the messages that you need to point you in the right direction to solve your problem.

Comment: @DavidWasser still i dont see any error which can cause calling fragment to launch parent activity with its attached fragment

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes turn on noHistory=false in AndroidManifest.xml can work. It's i think almost a forgotten thing.

**HOW ?**

Open AndroidManifest.xml file, locate the  tag for the file that containts onActivityResult() method and enter android:noHistory= "false"

**LIKE THIS !**

```
<activity
        android:name="MyActivityClassName"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:noHistory="false"
        />
```

Hope it help somebody.